# Программное удаление приложения Android из списка недавно запущенных приложений

Tags: android, android-sdk, процесс, firemonkey

Что происходит на уровне системы, когда мы нажимаем хардварную кнопку «приложения», и в окне «последние приложения» удаляем приложение? На пользовательском уровне приложение удаляется из списка, если у приложения был запущен сервис, тот теряет процесс приложения и перезапускается.

Необходимо повторить это действие пользователя (удаление программы из списка последних приложений) программно из самого приложения, со всеми сопутствующими процедурами системы. Если нет, тогда удаление из списка другим приложением.

Сокрытие приложение через манифест не подходит.

Кто может помочь в этом вопросе, помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: пробовали использовать `android.os.Process.sendSignal(pid, android.os.Process.SIGNAL_KILL);` Если приложение само себя, то можно `android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());` как-то так.

Comment: О! Да! Перепробовал уничтожать приложение множество способов. Процесс умирает, но приложение остается висеть в в списке последних. В моем случае это проблема, потому что пока я не удалю вручную приложение из списка после его закрытия и усиления, его сервис перезапускается, но не начинает принимать Broadcast Intents и StartService команды.

Comment: Так есть же кнопочка в Android monitor e, крестик красный, должен все прибить. :) Хотя вряд ли вам это поможет, но все же

Comment: Ну при чем здесь крестики? Я же говорю — программно удалить.

Comment: Это прибьет процесс, разве нет?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Только что проверял на API21 вот этот код - он работает - закрывает приложение и убирает из списка задач:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
{
    finishAndRemoveTask();
} else
{
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
    {
        finishAffinity();
    } else
    {
        finish();
    }
}
Process.killProcess(Process.myPid());
```

---

Похожий код в документации: [тык](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/android/103/intent/6780/end-application-with-exclude-from-recents#t=201607221827432505055)

Comment: Спасибо за решение.
Приложение удаляется из списка.
Но, видимо, метод finishAndRemoveTask() не выполняет те действия в системе, которые производятся при удалении задачи из списка вручную. Потому что моя проблема осталась — пока я не удалю вручную приложение из списка после его закрытия и уничтожения,  сервис приложения перезапускается, но не начинает принимать Broadcast Intents и StartService команды (

Comment: @PaxBeach, если четно, то я не доконца понял вашу проблему и задачу. Возможно у вас что-то не так в сервисе/ресивере

Comment: Действительно, проблема была в сервисе. Особенность работы с сервисами в RAD Studio. Переменную ресивера нельзя было объявлять в интерфейсе класса, вынес в глобальную переменную, и в купе с Вашим решением все завертелось как нужно.